# Is there a way to keyframe the action of applying/adding modifiers (or constraints for bones)

Tags: python, animation, armature, bones, bone.constraints

I'm new to scripting in Blender but I've made a tool for an easy IK/FK switch for myself. I've been testing the tool without keyframing and it functionally works great but what I didn't take into account was the fact that I made this tool by applying bone constraints and adding them to other bones when I switch meaning that while animating if I hit the switch, those modifiers change for the whole animation. Obviously this defeats the purpose of having an IK Switch. I could try to avoid applying/adding new constraints during animation but I'm not sure how the animation workflow would function if I was to try keyframing enabling and disabling different modifiers since disabling wouldn't keep previous changes. Thank you for any advice!

[image: The Hand IK works in the first play through but once it switches, the second play through constrains the arm]